# Where is Idea 2017 holds it editor font configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have installed community edition instead of EAP ultimate version but installation doesn't suggest me import previous version configuration, and i already don't remember name of the font i have used. Ultimate version configs resides in location `C:\Users\%user%\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\config`. From which of the xml config file i able to get font name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editor font settings are stored in **[IDE config](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)\options\editor.xml** file that is `C:\Users\%user%\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\config\options\editor.xml`.